# Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying the following code:

```
string text = "";
char c = 'd';
text += "abc" & c.ToString();
```

..but it returns an error 'Operator '&' cannot...' . It don't works even without ToString(). What's the problem converting char to string?

Comment: Yes :) In VB all conversions from data types to data types are much simpler, so I found it pretty hard to get these conversions right in C#.

Comment: Of course from my perspective conversions in VB are much *harder*. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't use `&` for string concatentation in C#, you use `+`

```
string text = ""; 
char c = 'd'; 
text += "abc" + c;
```

Answer (score 2):

The string concatenation operator is a plus sign in C#, not an ampersand.